# Visual Studio Code - Dart - how to place open brace on new line?

Tags: dart, newline

How do I configure Visual Studio Code to place an open brace on a new line?

Comment: If `dartfmt` is used there is no way to do that. I don't know if VSCode supports custom code formats.

Answer (score 6):

This is not currently possible. Dart Code uses the Dart SDK's language server for formatting, which uses `dart_style`, the package for `dartfmt`.

If you'd like to see support for a customisable formatter, please add a  to this issue:

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/914